# Issue with Sheet.FindAll Method

Tags: office-js

I am trying to find all of the cells that are an exact match to the string `"Sub-Total"`. When I run the below code, the code breaks prior to the second `context.sync()`. I am struggling to understand why the cells are not being found and bolded in the below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

When running the below, I would expect all cells in column A that are an exact match to `"Sub-Total"` would be bolded.

```
        Excel.run(function (context) {
            var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            var subTotals = sheet.findAll("Sub-Total", {
                completeMatch: true,
                matchCase: true
            });

            return context.sync().
                then(function () {
                    subTotals.format.font.bold = true;
                    var aaColumn = sheet.getRange("A:A");
                    aaColumn.format.autofitColumns();
                    return context.sync();
                })

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
```

The code will run for the first `context.sync` and then break thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, although you have an unnecessary `context.sync`. Try this:

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

    var subTotals = sheet.findAll("Sub-Total", {
      completeMatch: true,
      matchCase: true
    });

    subTotals.format.font.bold = false;
    var aaColumn = sheet.getRange("A:A");
    aaColumn.format.autofitColumns();

    return context.sync();
});
```

**UPDATE**:

Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/Rick-Kirkham/e1644815697451132a3f28959538c0f6) that you can import into [the Script Lab tool](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380862). Let's see if it works for you in Script Lab and then take it from there.

BTW, I can't see the context in which you are calling `Excel.run`, but it returns a Promise object, so you should try putting the `return` keyword in front of it. See the gist for an example.

Comment: For whatever reason I'm not getting any response when I run the above code. I've added error catching and there seems to still be nothing occurring. Any ideas on why this could be the case?